# getting an error while using Arrays.sort() in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am using ->

```
String ar[]=new String[n];
Arrays.sort(ar,new Comparator<String>());
```

I am getting the error as shown below

```
The method sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (String[], Comparator<String>)
```

What should i do??

Comment: [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) is an interface. How exactly are you instanciating it?

Answer (score 4):

Comparator is an interface. Hence you need to instatiate it annonymously and provce implementation

```
Arrays.sort(ar, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from providing your own implementation of Comparator (as seen in @SURESH ATTA answer) you can just simply use fact that String is implementing Comparable interface ([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)) and you can use sort method like this:

```
String[] strings = { " A ", " D ", " E ", " B ", " Z " };
Arrays.sort(strings);
```